# Formatting the text entered with commands in custom environment

Tags: formatting, punctuation, capitalization, strings

I want to create some kind of a to-do list. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myEnv}[1]{%
    \begin{center}%
        --- #1 ---%
    \end{center}
}{}

\newcommand*{\task}[2]{#1 (#2),}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myEnv}{1st week of November}
        \task{cycling}{probably}
        \task{swimming}{once per two days}
    \end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to modify the `myEnv` definition to achieve two things: 1) turn the first letter of the text inside the `myEnv` environment into its upper case and 2) automatically separate tasks with commas and end the whole text with a period. I want to keep entering the tasks this way because it allows to change an order of the tasks easily. So how should I make it? Is this actually doable?

The current result:
[image]

And the desired one:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I define the punctuation in `\seppunct` and set it *prior* to the given task.  So, initially, I set its value to nothing, once the first task is invoked, I set it to a comma.  And then, when the environment closes, I add a period.

As to the uppercase of the initial task, I have a macro `\MkUC` that is initially set to make its argument (the first character of the task) uppercase.  After the first task is complete, I redefine it to not capitalize the first letter in the task.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myEnv}[1]{%
    \def\seppunct{}%
    \def\MkUC##1{\uppercase{##1}}
    \begin{center}%
        --- #1 ---%
    \end{center}
}{.}

\newcommand*{\task}[2]{%
  \seppunct{} \MkUC#1 (#2)%
  \def\seppunct{,}%
  \def\MkUC##1{##1}%
  \ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myEnv}{1st week of November}
        \task{cycling}{probably}
        \task{swimming}{once per two days}
    \end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP asked in comments about support for capitalizing leading diacritics.  The easiest workaround while using the above code is to place the diacritic in a group as in `\task{{\"c}ycling}{probably}`.  However, as that can be considered annoying, here is a workaround that works with standard diacritics, but will still be fooled by special stuff like a leading `\ae`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myEnv}[1]{%
    \def\seppunct{}%
    \def\MkUC##1##2{%
      \ifcat A##1\uppercase{##1}\expandafter##2\else\uppercase{##1##2}\fi}
    \begin{center}%
        --- #1 ---%
    \end{center}
}{.}

\newcommand*{\task}[2]{%
  \seppunct{} \MkUC#1 (#2)%
  \def\seppunct{,}%
  \def\MkUC##1{##1}%
  \ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myEnv}{1st week of November}
        \task{cycling}{probably}
        \task{swimming}{once per two days}
    \end{myEnv}
    \begin{myEnv}{1st week of November}
        \task{\"cycling}{probably}
        \task{swimming}{once per two days}
    \end{myEnv}    
    \begin{myEnv}{1st week of November}
        \task{c\"ycling}{probably}
        \task{swimming}{once per two days}
    \end{myEnv}    
    \begin{myEnv}{1st week of November}
        \task{\ae gon}{conqueror}
        \task{swimming}{once per two days}
    \end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't suppose it can be so simple. But what is the aim of these `\relax` commands? The result without them seems to be the same. Moreover, I tried to extract `\MkUC` and `\def\MkUC#1#2\relax{\uppercase{#1}#2}` didn't work but `\def\MkUC#1#2{\uppercase{#1}#2}` seems to work fine.

Comment: @Jakbog Thank you for noting that.  It is out of habit of digesting the whole argument.  But in this case, since only the 1st token is operated on, there is no need for it, and the only difference arises if the first argument were blank, which is not a realistic scenario.  I will edit to simplify based on your comment.

Comment: In addition I realized that `\MkUC` doesn't affect letters containing diacritics. For example `\MkUC \'s` will produce `ś` instead of `Ś`. Is there easy way to fix it?

Comment: I think this issue is caused by using `\uppercase`. Maybe `\MakeUppercase` should fix it but this probably enforces modifications in `\MkUC` definition.

Comment: @Jakbog The easiest thing would be to embrace the diacritic, as in `\task{{\'c}ycling}{probably}`.  Is that a sufficient workaround or too painful?

Comment: It's better than nothing. Although a correct result using `\task{\'cycling}{probably}` or even `\task{ćycling}{probably}` (`inputenc` with `utf8` option) will be very helpful.

Comment: @Jakbog I will give it some thought, though an easy fix does not jump out at me.

Comment: @Jakbog See **SUPPLEMENT**

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It's almost perfect (although `\task{ćycling}{probably}` still doesn't work but it isn't a big problem, let's say) but I've spotted another issue. `\task{\'ccc}{probably}` works fine, `\task{cc\'c}{probably}` works fine too but `\task{c\'cc}{probably}` doesn't. Error occurs when the second letter contains diacritic. Of course `\task{c{\'c}c}{probably}` also works.

Comment: @Jakbog I added an `\expandafter` to address the case of diacritic in position #2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `expl3` via `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{todolist}{m}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  {\centering #1\par}
  \nopagebreak\vspace{\medskipamount}
 }
 {
  \noindent\jakbog_todolist:
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\task}{mm}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_jakbog_todolist_seq { #1~(#2) }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_jakbog_todolist_seq
\tl_new:N \l_jakbog_todolist_first_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_mixed_case:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jakbog_todolist:
 {
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_jakbog_todolist_seq \l_jakbog_todolist_first_tl
  \tl_mixed_case:V \l_jakbog_todolist_first_tl
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_jakbog_todolist_seq { ,~ }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_jakbog_todolist_seq { ,~ } .
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{todolist}{1st week of November}
  \task{cycling}{probably}
  \task{swimming}{once per two days}
\end{todolist}

\begin{todolist}{2nd week of November}
  \task{sleeping}{surely}
  \task{watching TV}{four hours per day}
  \task{drinking beer}{three every day}
\end{todolist}

\begin{todolist}{3rd week of November}
  \task{Sleeping}{definitely}
\end{todolist}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that `\task` stores the input in a sequence. At the end of the environment, the first item of the sequence is split off and passed through `\tl_mixed_case:n`. If the sequence is still not empty, “comma-space” is added; then the sequence is used with “comma-space” between item, with a final period.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with `xparse` but it seems to be very useful and I definitely will check it out. I think `environ` package is redundant in this solution, isn't it?

Comment: @Jakbog Yes, it’s redundant: a relic of a previous attempt.